# Difference between IOError and OSError?

Tags: python, exception, python-2.x

I am always getting confused on whether a function would raise an IOError or OSError (or both?). What is the principle rule behind these exception types, what is the difference between them and when is which raised?

I've initially thought OSError is for things like permission denial, but opening a file without permissions will raise an IOError.

Comment: *Changed in version 3.3: `EnvironmentError`, `IOError`, `WindowsError`, `VMSError`, `socket.error`, `select.error` and `mmap.error` have been merged into `OSError`.* E.g. just throw `OSError` and forget about `IOError`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks, I've added the Python 2 tag. Just throwing OSError sounds good to me, yet I'm always having trouble to know when a function like `shutil.copyfile()` or `os.access()` would raise IOError or OSError (always have to look it up)

Comment: Also see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3151/ for the background on this, it'll help put the two exceptions into perspective.

Comment: If you are getting confused by it - well, that's one reason to switch to Python 3 then.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Looks like a good read, thank you

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I do use Python 3 for standalone projects, but its a different story in an embedded Python environment. :)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

There is very little difference between the two types. In fact, even the core Python developers agreed that there is no real difference and removed `IOError` in Python 3 (it is now an alias for `OSError`). See [PEP 3151 - Reworking the OS and IO exception hierarchy](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3151/#confusing-set-of-os-related-exceptions):

> While some of these distinctions can be explained by implementation considerations, they are often not very logical at a higher level. The line separating `OSError` and `IOError`, for example, is often blurry. Consider the following:
>
> ```
> >>> os.remove("fff")
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'fff'
> >>> open("fff")
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'fff'
> ```

Yes, that's two different exception types with the *exact same error message*.

For your own code, stick to throwing `OSError`. For existing functions, check the documentation (it should detail what you need to catch), but you can safely catch both:

```
try:
    # ...
except (IOError, OSError):
    # handle error
```

Quoting the PEP again:

> In fact, it is hard to think of any situation where `OSError` should be caught but not `IOError`, or the reverse.

Comment: or: `except EnvironmentError:`  (which is then base class of WindowsError, mmap.error, shutil.Error, etc.  too on PY2)

Comment: As an aside, it's important to note that the problem isn't that there is no difference between O/S errors and I/O errors, but that Python was inconsistent. For an I/O error to be raised, Python should have stuck with "were it not for some error, specific to the device or request, the action would have succeeded."

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference between IOError and OSError cause they mostly appear on similar commands like opening a file or removing one.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't exacly answer the question but in case people don't know:

IOError stands for input/output error, and OSError stands for operating system error.