# os.makedirs() Occasionally Fails

Tags: python, file-io, intermittent

I have a program that - on startup - checks to see if the user-supplied output directory exists.  If the directory can not be found the program attempts to create it:

```
if not os.path.exists(path):
  os.makedirs(path)
```

Path is a standard absolute path to a directory such as '/mnt/share/path/to/output'

It works about 75% of the time.  The rest of the time I get either "exception.OSError," or "exception.IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory."  Both exceptions have the same error number and text.

Why is this happening?  I don't see how it would be permissions related or anything like that - I am writing as myself to directories I own and control - and again it works the other 3 out of 4 times.  I am writing the same directory to the same place every time and deleting it recursively between program invocations for testing.  It is writing to a remote share (NFS) if that matters at all.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is an issue of a **Race Condition** take a look at this answer [Race Condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14574518/how-does-using-the-try-statement-avoid-a-race-condition), Hope it helps.

Comment: How is it an example of a race condition?  Nothing is competing to access or create this directory tree.  By the time the program executes, the directory has already been removed.

Comment: Read these two answer maybe it'll clear things up for you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29347790/difference-between-ioerror-and-oserror

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18973418/os-mkdirpath-returns-oserror-when-directory-does-not-exist